# Lotus Notes 6.5 and 7 put borders around my html elements

Tags: html, email, border, lotus-notes, newsletter

I am testing a self made newsletter on emailonacid.com and the result of Lotus Notes 6.5 and 7 show me big black borders around everything.

I already put `border="0"`, `cellpadding="0"` and `cellspacing="0"` on every `table` and `"border: none"` + `"border-spacing: 0"` on every element.

Did someone have the same problem in the past and knows how to fix it?

Here is a picture of the test: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJNMb.jpg

Comment: Lotus Notes 6.5 and 7 have very limited support for CSS. Hence these domains will not render  properly

Comment: Ye but without telling them to put a border they should render no border right?

Comment: Do you mind posting your HTML? I had an issue like this a while back. Turned out Lotus Notes was converting a defined, one sided, coloured border to a thick 2px black border incasing the entire element.

Answer (score 0):

Update to a current version of Notes and Domino (7.0 was released in August 2005, a decade ago!). If you still have problems, look at CoexLink Fidelity from GeniiSoft.

Also try to use "0px" instead of just "0" for border thickness.

Comment: The Newsletter is going to be send to other people, so I don't need to update Notes. And using "0px" instead of "0" isn't helping.

Comment: So what is the problem? You are sending the email from an external service to a number of external recipients, and your problem is that when you receive your test mail in your mailbox in Notes 7 it looks bad because you use a 10 your old version? But you don't want to update to a recent version?

Also, you have way too many tables in yrou newsletter. Today you use CSS to position elements, not tables. And around the image you can use margin and padding to get the spacing you require, instead of using small table cells. (Don't use tools like Dreamweaver, it adds a lot oc junk like that).

Comment: Maybe you should read yourself into coding newsletters before you answer to a question like the one i asked. Using tables to position is a safe way at newsletters. And i want to send the newsletter to other people so there is no reason updating my notes version cause the others could use notes and will see the newsletter in a really ugly way.

Comment: Very few people use ancient versions of Notes, though. Have you looked at it in the 8.5.x client?
Also, your question is somewhat unclear. "the result of Lotus Notes 6.5 and 7 show me..." could mean that you send it out using Notes 6.5/7. The proper thing to say would have been "the result, viewing it IN the Lotus Notes 6.5 and 7 clients shows me..."

If you are a developer, you should know how to be specific and clear in your communication. ;-)

Comment: Maybe it's just cause i am 18 years old and learning to develop :)

Comment: So why use a Notes version that came out when you were in Kindergarten? ;-)

Comment: Cause i want the newsletter to display the same at nearly all email clients ;-)